# read_excel when tab starts with empty cell

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to read an excel file with multiple sheets as follows:

```
sumtech = pd.read_excel('excelfile.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
```

One of the sheets has the following format:

```
          c3   c4
d1   d2   d3   d4
b1   b2   b3   b4
```

Since this sheet starts with empty cells (no header), only columns 3 and 4 are read. How do I tell pandas to read the whole table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `header=None`. You can later define the columns by hand or use the first row to use as column names, also use `skiprows` to your advantage -

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('excelfile.xlsx', header=None, skiprows=1)
df.columns = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4']

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   c1  c2  c3  c4
0  d1  d2  d3  d4
1  b1  b2  b3  b4
```

Comment: For my case, the header of the tabs are not the same. One tab may have different headers than the one who is missing some column names. Any suggestions for that case?

Comment: Provide the column names in df.columns as given in the answer